# A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'D:\Program Files\dotnet'

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-webjobs

i have .netCore Azure web job and it is moves to pending restart state once deployed with following error.

A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'D:\Program Files\dotnet'

Comment: Have you by chance hard coded this - `D:\Program Files\dotnet` in your code? And can you also see if this file is deployed through Kudu Console?

Comment: no hard code. and i dont see this file through kudu console.as web job deployed at wwrrot/..../.. location not in D:program files .web job struck at pending restart with above error

Comment: Is there any setting which is required by Web Job and not included in the App Configuration of App service? Can you verify? I assume it works well in local,

Comment: yes it works well in local.what setting are you talking about as far as i know every thing is taken care.can you help me understanding what is the setting you want me to look for.

Comment: If your Web App is consuming any setting, it needs to be added in Your_App_Service > Configuration > Application settings

Comment: yes all those taken care

Comment: Can you try out solutions provided here? - https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3569